# Is it possible to post a status update and adding an image file with facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to post a status update to my feed and add a photo residing on disk, using the facebook graph api. 
Is this possible or must I provide be a hyperlink address to the image?
I know it's possible to add a photo to an album using the [Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object's `source` parameter but I'm looking for a way to do a status update with a image file attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible as we have published images directly to Albums and Walls using the Facebook C# API which posts to the graph API

We use the FacebookMediaObject to achieve this but I believe this simply creates the post form data required. Here is out code so you can take a look if it helps:

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(entry.AccessToken);
var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = filename,
                ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            };
var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
mediaObject.SetValue(fileBytes);

IDictionary<string, object> upload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
upload.Add("name", imagename);
upload.Add("message", message);
upload.Add("@file.jpg", mediaObject);

var result = facebookClient.Post("/" + albumId + "/photos", upload) as JsonObject;
```

Note the field name of "@file.jpg" which the mediaObject is assigned.

hope this helps.

### Update

You may have to post the image to the users wall first and recieve an object ID which you can then reference in the post with the object_id field.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean first uploading the photo to an album and then posting an update to the wall with a link to this photo?

Comment: If you use the user's id instead of the albumid in the post then it goes to their default photo collection I believe

Comment: The problem is that the above is not really a status update but a photo upload. When trying this, the photo got added to the album but I had to click the album to get this info, so the status feed wasn't updated. It did however work as intended when posting to the wall photo album which was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Without Using Facebook SDK. Here is the code to upload image via direct Facebook API.

```
            var ImagePath = "480.jpg";
            var caption = "Description of Photo";
            string fullurl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?caption={0}&access_token={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(caption), accessToken);
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var returnVar = client.UploadFile(fullurl, ImagePath);
```