# Using Facebook for an online magic contest (Video upload /

Tags: facebook, video, embed

I am currently developing a new website / facebook app for an online magic competition. I am hoping most of the functionality can come from Facebook's own services, and would like your feedback on how plausible our goals are.

Essentially there will be two types of users: magicians and voters. Magicians will upload a video of them performing a trick (or select a video they have already uploaded). Voters will vote for their favourite magicians, and be able to post these videos to their wall.

Are these possible:

- Video upload to Facebook - I have had a search, but the only method I found uses the depreciated REST API. Is there a newer implementation?
- Video download - After a user has uploaded a video are they (or can we) able to download their video from Facebook?
- Embedding magicians Facebook videos on the standalone website?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can still upload videos and photos using the graph api. We have done this into galleries for a number of clients.

see here for a picture example (works with other media objects such as videos):

[Is it possible to post a status update and adding an image file with facebook graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225601/is-it-possible-to-post-a-status-update-and-adding-an-image-file-with-facebook-gr/8225753#8225753)

The problems you may face though are the issues of managing and approving content in the site.

One solution we have found is to combine YouTube API and Facebook to get the best of both worlds. you can now embed a YouTube uploader in your site / app which will post videos into a channel of yours but have an approval app to control what lands. Then add any voting mechanism of your choice to the stream of videos. You can use YouTube likes, Facebook likes or your own. Take a look at this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1zgFlCw8Aw

You can embed a YouTube channel into Facebook easily too:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pClpKAnddGI

Also using youtube, you can spread your net farther to reach more of an audience.

Hope this can be of some help. (No, I don't work for YouTube just find using more than one platform better)

Comment: Thanks Richard. My main concern with using YouTube hosting is that we are hoping to gain ad revenue to support the competition. Does this violate their T&C?